# HP Envy Windows 10 - touchpad does not stay disabled

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, hp-envy

My wife has a lovely laptop - HP Envy.  The problem?  Every single day she screams that the damned touchpad is back on.  I go find the settings to disable and she is golden for a while.  A restart or return from sleep... and voila, re-enabled.  I have set the setting to fully disable, agreeing with the warning that I am disabling the only active synaptic pointing device.  I have tried to set the setting so it is only "on" when a mouse is not attached.  Same behavior.  I have updated the synaptic pointing device drivers.  Still no change.  Honestly, the next step could be opening up the case and starting to yank wires at this point.  I have never not been able to turn off these devices... what the heck is wrong with Windows 10???? Gahhh!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I can say it was quite annoying.  But I saw on another site the answer and tried it myself and it works.

The latest (Newest) driver 19.o.19.1 works.  You can get it here.... 
http://drivers.synaptics.com/Synaptics_v19_0_19_1__C__x86-x64__Win10__Signed__MS_Win10_UXUI_PS2_SMbus.zip

I can say the mouse on my laptop now stays disabled when I have the external plugged in.  I rebooted many times and it is still disabled.

Hope this helps.
Kacie